# How to pass parameter from controller to view?

Tags: extjs

I am loading a view like :

```
items:[{
          xtype :<xtype>
       }],
```

The class for  has been included in "requires" in this controller.
How can I pass a parameter to the view that will be loaded? I don't wish to use config or set something in global namespace. My idea is to use same view with multiple parameters.

Comment: Similarly, I want to pass parameter from view to store that has been defined within the view (by "store" keyword). How may I do it?

Comment: Just add the params to the structure like this: `items [{xtype: <xtype], param1 : <param>, param.2 : <param}]`